# How to have java executor with same thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

For some proposes, I need to create an `Executor` which has always one same thread.

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

Above examples create one thread pool but when work is done then the thread will be ended and again created a new one if a new task is passed to the executor.

So I figured out something like this:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(1,1,Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
```

it seems that works but I have doubts if it's the right approach. Can someone show a better/correct way?

Comment: I can understand why you might be concerned about the overhead of destroying and re-creating the worker thread, but why does the _identity_ of the worker thread matter to your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) (emphasis mine):

> Creates an `Executor` that uses a single worker thread operating off an unbounded queue. **(Note however that if this single thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.)** Tasks are guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent `newFixedThreadPool(1)` the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.

Comment: @LunaVulpo it guarantees that a single thread will be utilised until the first failure